# Can we invoke an iOS8 extension using javascript?

Tags: ios8, ios8-extension

I am working on an iOS8 extension in which I need to invoke the extension using a button on a website.
Is it possible to invoke the extension without using the Share button on Safari?

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible. Extension can only be invoked with the action button in Safari